# put thousands of files, in folders named a certain way

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

i have a folder, named test, which has only jpeg files in it. Thousand of files. i need to put these thousands of files, named like 1.jpg, 2.jpg... 345623.jpg, into subfolders that will have a name like 001000, 002000, each containing 1000 files. So i need to move all jpg files from test folder, into subfolders that contain each 1000 jpg files, with the most performant efficient way.

What i have so far is:

```
i=1;while read l;do mkdir $i;mv $l $((i++));done< <(ls|xargs -n1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f \
| split -l 1000 -a 3 --numeric-suffixes=1 \
  --filter='target="${FILE}000"; mkdir "$target" && xargs -d "\n" mv -t "$target"' \
  - ''
```

Explanation:

- `find . -type f` finds files (also in subdirectories, but I believe in your case there are no subdirectories yet).
- `split -l 1000 -a 3 --numeric-suffixes=1 ... - ''` reads from its stdin (`-`) and splits data into chunks, each chunk 1000 lines long (`-l 1000`). For each chunk a "name" is associated consisting in the empty prefix (`''`) and numeric suffix starting from 1 (`--numeric-suffixes=1`) of the length 3 (`-a 3`). In effect at this point the names are `001`, `002` and so on.
- `--filter=...` runs the specified command separately for each chunk, the respective name is available as `$FILE`. The command to run is

  ```
  target="${FILE}000"; mkdir "$target" && xargs -d "\n" mv -t "$target"
  ```

  - `target="${FILE}000"` converts the name like `001` or `002` to future directory name you want (`001000` or `002000` etc.) and stores this in the `target` variable.
  - `mkdir "$target"` creates a new directory with the desired name.
  - `xargs -d "\n" ...` reads the entire chunk (1000 filepaths, or less in the last chunk) and uses each whole line (newline as delimiter: `-d "\n"`) as an argument to the command that follows.

    - `mv -t "$target"` moves objects (passed by `xargs`) to the newly created directory.

Notes:

- The command doesn't care for file names. `345623.jpg` won't necessarily end up in `346000/`. Possible reasons:

  - `find` doesn't sort; but even if you put `sort -n` between `find` and `split`, it may be...
  - there are gaps in numbering. `split` will take 1000 entries, no matter what (unless it's the last chunk; if so, then 1000 or less).
- `mkdir ... && xargs ...` won't run `xargs` if `mkdir` fails (beware of existing directories).
- Use `cp -l -t "$target"` instead of `mv -t "$target"` to create hardlinks in directories, leaving already existing entries in the current directory intact. This way, in case something goes wrong, just `rm -r` the directories and start anew. With `mv`, if the task is interrupted, you will end up with some files moved, some not; this may be a mess.
- I think `-a 3` won't get you past `999` (`999000` after appending trailing zeros). If `split` needs to create more chunks, it will fail in the middle of its job. For this reason make sure `999` is enough before you run the command.
- Names with newlines will break the code (in general, your file names look fine).